# Why is App Engine Returning the Wrong Application ID?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The App Engine Dev Server [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver) says the following:

> The development server simulates the production App Engine service. One way in which it does this is to prepend a string (`dev~`) to the `APPLICATION_ID`environment variable. Google recommends always getting the application ID using `get_application_id`

---

In my application, I use different resources locally than I do on production. As such, I have the following for when I startup the App Engine instance:

```
import logging

from google.appengine.api.app_identity import app_identity
# ...
# other imports
# ...

DEV_IDENTIFIER = 'dev~'
application_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
is_development = DEV_IDENTIFIER in application_id

logging.info("The application ID is '%s'")
if is_development:
    logging.warning("Using development configuration")

    # ...
    # set up application for development
    # ...

 # ...
```

Nevertheless, when I start my local dev server via the command line with `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`, I get the following output in my console:

```
INFO: The application ID is 'development-application'
WARNING: Using development configuration
```

Evidently, the `dev~` identifier that the documentation claims will be preprended to my application ID is absent. I have also tried to use the App Engine Launcher UI to see if that changed anything, but it did not.

Note that 'development-application' is the name of my actual application, but I expected it to be 'dev~development-application'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Google recommends always getting the application ID using get_application_id

But, that's if you cared about the *application ID* -- you don't: you care about the *partition*. Check out the source -- it's published at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/app_identity/app_identity.py .

`get_app_identity` uses `os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID')` then passes that to internal function `_ParseFullAppId` -- which splits it by `_PARTITION_SEPARATOR = '~'` (thus removing again the `dev~` prefix that `dev_appserver.py` prepended to the environment variable). That's returned as the "partition" to `get_app_identity` (which ignores it, only returning the application ID in the strict sense).

Unfortunately, there is no architected way to get just the partition (which is in fact all you care about).

I would recommend that, to distinguish whether you're running locally or "in production" (i.e, on Google's servers at appspot.com), in order to access different resources in each case, you take inspiration from the way Google's own example does it -- specifically, check out the `app.py` example at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_Using_a_local_MySQL_instance_during_development .

In that example, the point is to access a Cloud SQL instance if you're running in production, but a local MySQL instance instead if you're running locally. But that's secondary -- let's focus instead on, how does Google's own example tell which is the case? The relevant code is...:

```
if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
      os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
      ...snipped: what to do if you're in production!...
    else:
      ...snipped: what to do if you're in the local server!...
```

So, this is the test I'd recommend you use.

Well, as a Python guru, I'm actually slightly embarassed that my colleagues are using this slightly-inferior Python code (with two calls to `os.getenv`) -- me, I'd code it as follows...:

```
in_prod = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/')
if in_prod:
    ...whatever you want to do if we're in production...
else:
    ...whatever you want to do if we're in the local server...
```

but, this is exactly the same semantics, just expressed in more elegant Python (exploiting the second optional argument to `os.getenv` to supply a default value).

I'll be trying to get this small Python improvement into that example *and* to also place it in the doc page you were using (there's no reason anybody just needing to find out if their app is being run in prod or locally should ever have looked at the docs about Cloud SQL use -- so, this *is* a documentation goof on our part, and, I apologize). But, while I'm working to get our docs improved, I hope this SO answer is enough to let you proceed confidently.

Comment: Is there a version of the documentation that links directly to the source that is being discussed? I've found that the docs I've been looking at are great when I need to understand a concept, but when I need to do something a bit more complicated, it's tough to track down the source.

Comment: All the SDK sources can be browsed online at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython , or, you can download them for perusing on your local machine at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/checkout and in many other ways.

Answer (score 2):

That documentation seems wrong, when I run the commands locally it just spits out the name from app.yaml.

That being said, we use

```
import os
os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Dev')
```

to check if it is the dev appserver.

Comment: just ran `os.getenv("APPLICATION_ID"))` and it returned the version of the app with the prepended `dev~`, so that is interesting.

Comment: I think they wrote it backwards, then. As they have it, `os.getenv("APPLICATION_ID"))` is not guaranteed to yield the proper environment-specific application ID, but the approach I used above is.

Comment: @nmagerko, point is, the application ID is *NOT* environment-specific -- it's always the string in your app.yaml; a prefix such as `dev~` is known as a "partition" and is not part of the application ID. I do agree the documentation is confusing on these points, and I'm working to improve it, as per my answer that you kindly accepted.

Comment: @AlexMartelli right, I think I understand now. I believe my comment above was posted before I saw your answer